# How can I use Open Sea Maps on a Mac?

Tags: macos

How can I use Open Sea Maps on a Mac? I want to make waypoints on sea marks, lighthouses, islets and similar and export to the plotter I use in my boat.

Comment: Please describe in **detail** the problem you are facing in installing / using it - what have you tried, does it not work as expected, do you get an error message, etc. Also tell us what Mac model you have and the macOS version on it.

Comment: @sfxedit Do you know what Open Sea Maps are?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nohillside Nothing, because there are no known ways to use a Mac (there are Windows solutions), hence the question.

Comment: Then please add those details to the question, we can't know what you have tried. From what I gather so far, you are looking for an application which uses Open Sea Maps and allow to plan boat trips?

Comment: @nohillside That is philosophically pointless. The list of what I can't try is infinite, e.g., I haven't tried walking my dog on the moon, I haven't tried to prove 1 + 1 = 3, I haven't tried to melt iron in my fridge, I haven't tried to ask Santa Claus for help ad infinitum. You have understood what I try to achieve perfectly fine, in other words, the question is clear and comprehensible and needs no further clarification for the audience that might be able to assist.

Comment: I made a rather wild guess based on various comments. Based on experience people on SE sites will ignore questions if they need to pull relevant details from comments. Please have a look at https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation/ to see what is important when asking for software recommendations.

Comment: @nohillside The question makes perfect sense for anyone who know the slightest about Opensea Map.

Comment: @hensti If you can make this question more accessible to a broader audience, please edit accordingly. The answers to the [meta question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/what-is-unclear-with-this-question) you raised last year should give some ideas on what the AD community thinks about ways to improve it. Please also keep the [Code of Conduct](https://apple.stackexchange.com/conduct) in mind when interacting with the site and other people here.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://map.openseamap.org/ in Safari or your favourite web browser.

Comment: And then what.?

Comment: @d-b It’s the map itself, that’s it! If this doesn’t answer your question, I think it’s unclear.

Comment: You didn't read the second (last) sentence in the question "I want to make waypoints on sea marks, lighthouses, islets and similar and export to the plotter I use in my boat."

Comment: @d-b Here, we can only clarify specific doubts and guide you on how to use Apple products. We cannot teach you how to use a software. For help with any non-apple software, you will have to read the manual and tutorial - http://openseamap.org/index.php?id=videoundtutorial&L=1 or ask in forums / communities dedicated to that particular product - http://forum.openseamap.org/ ... We can certainly help you if any issue you are facing is because of a mac or macOS. But for that too, you have to provide us *specific* details of the issue you are facing. Your current question is too broad.

Comment: @sfxedit Can you explain how to create a waypoint in Opensea Map on a Mac?

Comment: @hensti A better place for this question is at https://forum.openseamap.org/